# Progressbar in angular

Tags: html, angularjs

I want to make Progressbar in Angular.js in decimal format, simple format, times based Progressbar. Someone could pls help !

E.g.
Start Timer {{ counter }}/{{ max }} = {{ (counter/max)*100 }}%
Start Timer 20/30 = 66.66666666666666%

Here is `example.js`:

```
angular.module('plunker', ['ui.bootstrap']);

var ProgressDemoCtrl = function ($scope) {
    $scope.max = 200;
    $scope.random = function () {
        var value = Math.floor((Math.random() * 100) + 1);
        var type;

        if (value < 25) {
            type = 'success';
        } else if (value < 50) {
            type = 'info';
        } else if (value < 75) {
            type = 'warning';
        } else {
            type = 'danger';
        }

        $scope.showWarning = (type === 'danger' || type === 'warning');
        $scope.dynamic = value;
        $scope.type = type;
    };

var app = angular.module('plunker', ['ui.bootstrap']);

app.controller('ProgressDemoCtrl', function ($scope) {
    $scope.value = 40;
    $scope.state = "progress-bar-success";
    $scope.myStyle = {width: $scope.value + '%'};
});

$scope.random();

$scope.randomStacked = function() { $scope.stacked = [];

var types = ['success', 'info', 'warning', 'danger']; for (var i = 0, n = Math.floor((Math.random() * 4) + 1); i < n; i++) { var index = Math.floor((Math.random() * 4));

$scope.stacked.push({ value: Math.floor((Math.random() * 30) + 1),

type: types[index] }); } }; $scope.randomStacked(); };

var app = angular.module('progressApp',['nprogress']); var MainCtrl = function($scope,ngProgress){ }
```

Comment: I tried to clean u the code, but it's a real mess. It doesn't make any sense. Please, provide proper code.

Comment: check out the progress bar from the ui.bootstrap project instead

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I use this round progress ba directive, works pretty well:

http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=w2qrYL0Le24

https://github.com/angular-directives/angular-round-progress-directive

If you need a rectangular one give me a buzz I, have a custom directive implemented.

If you need two decimal numbers you only have to adjust the font size.

Test with two decimals:

[image]

Code to change (configuring ang:roundprogress directive)

```
data-round-progress-label-font="80pt Arial"
```

Whole markup

```
<div ang:round:progress data-round-progress-model="roundProgressData"
                        data-round-progress-width="500"
                        data-round-progress-height="500"
                        data-round-progress-outer-circle-width="40"
                        data-round-progress-inner-circle-width="10"
                        data-round-progress-outer-circle-radius="200"
                        data-round-progress-inner-circle-radius="140"
                        data-round-progress-label-font="80pt Arial"
                        data-round-progress-outer-circle-background-color="#505769"
                        data-round-progress-outer-circle-foreground-color="#12eeb9"
                        data-round-progress-inner-circle-color="#505769"
                        data-round-progress-label-color="#fff"></div>
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply I need a custom Progrss Bar where Progressbar should be based on decimal format like it should increase in decimal format 10.00 to 100.00

Comment: Updated the answer, tell if that's what you are looking for, thanks.

Comment: Thank you so much . I am satisfied with the logic you provided Thanks again.

Comment: sorry the decimal one is not cleared could u please elaborate it again.

Comment: You bind a value, you can go incrementing the value and it will be displayed in the round circle indicator, the only thing is that you need setup an smaller font to fit the text inside the circle.

Comment: This plugin does have some bug.. This is not working within ng-repeat.. :/